# the mame.ini file path not used

Tags: mame

I upgraded from sdlmame .148 to .159. `/etc/games/sdlmame/mame.ini` is no longer being read. I must keep the mame.ini in the same directory location that I run sdlmame at for the mame.ini file to be read. Is something broken or is this the new expected behavior?

Comment: No success. The only way sdlmame will read mame.ini is if I run it in the same directory. It's like it looks for the mame.ini only as `./mame.ini`

Answer (score 2):

This is the original intended behavior of Mame. The previous behavior was customized in the code.